# Broken "edit" link on comments

Tags: bug, comments

Why not hide the "edit" link on comments after 5-7 minutes?

I hate adding additional thoughts/ideas to a comment only to have them "bounce back" when I click "Save Edits". Old comments don't offer "edit", but many comments, especially in the heat of battle, offer a functionality that's not actually available. It can waste time and effort, which isn't satisfying.

Users should not encounter unexpected error messages by following on-screen guidance.

edit:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324387 is not answered, and the activity centers around the first case, commenting on a deleted post. I think that case affects few users.

a problem akin to "losing form values" is the number one UX annoyance and has a relatively simple fix: set a timer in javascript when the comment is first posted, and show a warning if editing 4:40 minutes later. even just turning the editor background pale orange as a "20 second" warning could really improve the experience.

Comment: I created some time ago a [comment timer](https://gist.github.com/rschrieken/8a3b04390b7fb3600c8056b039a21d24) but it only shows while you have the edit link, not while you are editing. I don't have time now to add that feature but if anyone want to take a shot at it, be my guest.

Comment: i don't see any answer linked for the problem, and i think a relatively simple script could look at the comment time and flip a warning if it's been 4 or 5 mins since then, no need to poll or use any server resources. i'll probably use stack regardless, but it is an annoyance when you see an error message after doing what was told.

Comment: the problem is that people are typing more things into a box the client knows can't be saved, without warning.